# Lintian warnings executable-not-elf-or-script

Tags: warnings, debian, package

When i test my debian package with lintian i get the following warning:

```
executable-not-elf-or-script usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11/rss_reader.php
```

Does anyone know why lintian show this warning.

Answer (score 2):

That file, rss_reader.php, has the +x permissions bit set, making it executable, but it isn't an ELF binary and it isn't a script with #! at the start. It therefore can't be executed by a standard linux kernel (there are modules to allow other binary formats to be executed).

In this particular case, although PHP scripts can be given a #! line and made executable, if they're part of a web application this probably isn't what you want. You should probably just remove the +x bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -x /usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11/rss_reader.php
```

this will remove the EXECUTION bit from it and Lintian will not print the warning.